# OpenCV how to check if face has been found

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Thanks for reading, I have modified OpenCV's Cascade Classifier to detect a face on a static image. I am now trying to work out whether or not a face has been found by the program (which then displays circles around the eyes and mouth of the inputted image), but I am not sure how to go about this.

For reference, here is my display function, a modified version of the OpenCV tutorial for facial detection.

Any tips or even high-level explanations would be greatly appreciated

```
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
   std::cout << "detectAndDisplay called" << endl;

   std::vector<Rect> faces;
   Mat frame_gray;

   cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
   equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

   //-- Detect faces
   face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

   for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
   {
      Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
      ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

      Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
      std::vector<Rect> eyes;

      //-- In each face, detect eyes
      eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

      for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
      {
          Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
          int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
          circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
      }
 }
   //-- Show what you got
   imshow( window_name, frame );
 }
```

Comment: If no face is detected, then `faces.size()` will be `0`.

Comment: Oh ok great thank you, I will try that